# Use ASP NET configured JSON MediaFormatter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

I have my json media type formatter configured in my global.asax as usual

```
Dim jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType(Of JsonMediaTypeFormatter).First()
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

How can I now instantiate this one else where in my app? Currently I just know it is used for example for my api controllers but I would like to instantiate it or use the configured formatter in the index file, to bootstrap some json data in a script tag for example...

Comment: might wanna tag this vb.net instead of c#

Comment: you can answer in c# if you want, in the end both become the same...